# Understanding "for value1,value2 in xx"

Tags: python, for-loop

Can anyone explain me what the below means?

```
for value1,value2 in List1:
           do_something()
```

I understand that

```
for x1 in List2:
        do_something()
```

here for iterates over `List2` and `x1` is reference to each item in `List2`, but I don't get what the first one does.

Answer (score 4):

Just like

```
for x in seq:
```

iterates over `seq` and assigns every element to `x`,

```
for a, b in seq:
```

will iterate over `seq` and assign every element to `a, b`. It's equivalent to

```
for x in seq:
    a, b = x
```

What does `a, b = x` do? Well, it's sequence unpacking. Python will attempt to treat `x` as a 2-element sequence and assign the elements of `x` to `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

The first one does [sequence unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). It is also possible on an normal assignment:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
a, b, c = mylist
```

assigns the elements of the list to the variables `a`, `b` and `c`.

The same as well works in a loop.

```
for x in iterable:
    a, b, c = x
```

can be shortened to

```
for a, b, c in iterable:
    ...
```

if iterable is an iterable which only contains elements (mostly tuples) of 3 items such as

```
[(1, 2, 3), (5, 4, 3), etc.]
```